# Holomorphy: Differentiable vs. Continuously Differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an open domain $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$.

Consider a merely differentiable function $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$.

Then it is continuously differentiable. How do I prove this?

*(So to say holomorphic functions are nice.)*

Moreover, do the proof of analyticity of holomorphic functions implicitely use the above?

Comment: For the sake of keeping this self-contained: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions

Comment: You should say a merely *complex* differentiable function. (One could interpret this as real differentiable.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I just noticed: Analyticity of holomorphic functions uses Cauchy's Integral Formula, that uses Cauchy's theorem and that uses continuity of partial derivatives (at least the standard proof as stated [here on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Proof)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generalization of Cauchy's theorem that you want is the [Cauchy–Goursat theorem](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/4320/cauchygoursat.pdf). It requires only the complex-differentiability of $f$, not that this derivative be continuous. (To pass from the theorem given to the analyticity of $f$, use [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).) Note that this requires that $U$ be simply connected, but as Freeze_S points out, we need only restrict to an open ball about a point and show that the derivative is continuous in this neighborhood, since continuity is a local property.

More generally maybe you want the [Looman–Menchoff theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem): any continuous complex-valued function that has all partial derivatives, and whose partial derivatives satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, is complex analytic.

Comment: Nice thanks so it is true? For a not simply connected domain you can just restrict to an open disk around any point within the domain, can't you?

Comment: Good point, @Freeze_S. And yes, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

By , e.g., Cauchy's theorem, and holomorphic function is not only infinitely-differentiable, but also analytic.

Comment: But the proof for Cauchy's theorem I saw on wiki uses continuity of it's partial derivative. Isn't that a circular argument?

Comment: Does it use Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: Nope, Cauchy's theorem uses Green's theorem. Cauchy's integral formula is given as corollary of Cauchy's theorem on wiki.

Comment: O.K, sorry, so it is more complicated than I thought.